# What's the correct way to load a new set of metrics/horizons?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cubism.js

What's the correct way to load a new set of metrics/horizons?
i.e. if a user were allowed to choose from a list of metrics in a multi-select.

Right now, I have a working implementation that simply runs
`d3.select('#graph1').html('');`
and reruns the horizon setup  `d3.select("#graph1").selectAll(".horizon").data(my_datum.map(load_metric)).enter().insert("div", ".bottom");` BUT this seems to cause all previously loaded to to disappear from the horizon after an incremental set is loaded.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cubism, but in D3 you would use the enter/update/exit pattern described e.g. in [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html).

Comment: I read the docs some more and found: `d3.select(".horizon").call(horizon.remove).remove();` BUT this doesn't work if the horizons are created in chain call `d3.select("body").selectAll(".horizon").data(metrics).enter().append("div").attr("class", "horizon").call(horizon);`

https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Horizon#wiki-remove